# I wish to merge two SO accounts, both are Google logins

Tags: support, merge-accounts, google

I want to merge my stackoverflow accounts that I login with my Google Accounts (for work and personal).

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Sure it can be done. Use the [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form to request a merge.

Comment: I thought it might be a different process for Google logins

Comment: To clarify - that will merge your Stack Exchange accounts - not your Google accounts.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Oded. I thought that it might be harder to merge to SO accounts from Google logins than regular SO accounts.

Comment: Most "regular SO accounts" use Google logins ;)

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  Should I delete this question?

Comment: You can leave it - makes for a good search target